# How to use Python to initiate MongoDB RepSet and then create the first admin user?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am trying setup a mongoDB RepSet with python, I have 2 replicas connected, but I can not figure out how to create the first admin user use pymongo.

I know I can create first Admin user using mongo shell as follow

```
db.getSiblingDB("admin").createUser({
      user : "main_admin",
      pwd  : "abc123",
      roles: [ { role: "root", db: "admin" } ]
 });
```

After create an admin user with mongo shell, I have no problem to use this python line  `client.testdb.add_user('newTestUser', 'Test123', roles=[{'role':'readWrite','db':'testdb'}])` to create a user.

**But, is there a way to create the first admin user with pymongo?**

Notes:

Command to start mongod:

```
mongod --bind_ip 0.0.0.0 --replSet MainRepSet --auth --clusterAuthMode keyFile \
       --keyFile /etc/secrets-volume/internalAuthMongoDBKeyfile --setParameter authenticationMechanisms=SCRAM-SHA-1  > /tmp/log &
```

python code for creating rs

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
conf = {'_id': "MainRepSet", 'members': [
       { '_id': 0, 'host' : "operations-mongo-0.operations-    mongo.governor.svc.cluster.local:27017" },
       { '_id': 3, 'host' : "operations-mongo-3.operations-    mongo.governor.svc.cluster.local:27017" }
]}
client.admin.command("replSetInitiate",conf)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you can't do that just with `pymongo`. You could use either `os` or `subprocess` modules along with `pymongo`.

You would to start `mongod` without `auth` enabled, create your user, shutdown `mongo` and then restart with `auth` enabled:

Presuming your were running on the localhost, something like:

```
from subprocess import call
from pymongo import MongoClient

call(["mongod", "-f mongoNonAuth.conf"])

client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
db = client["admin"]

db.command("createUser", "admin", pwd="password", roles=["root"])
db.command("shutdown")

call(["mongod", "-f mongoAuth.conf"])

client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017, 
         username="user name", password="pass/word")
```

Please note: Above code not tested

More info on `subprocess` vs `os`[Calling an external command in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python)